Is there any video of an air-to-air missile shooting down an aircraft?
I was curious, is there is any video of a missile shooting down an aircraft?
I have looked around, and I can’t seem to find anything substantial.
(Anything I did find was fake, such as this)
Air-to-air is what I’m looking for, but surface-to-air also counts.

@Wyatt I'm not sure of the two downvoters, but I think this is a bit off-topic (only a little). Also, it lacks research effort, there's quite a lot of actual footage if you search around the web. Finally, it's too broad. All the more reason to downvote, since it is the combination of all downvote reasons.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 If you hover over the downvote button, it says to downvote if there is no research effort. I did research, evidenced by the linked video of my failed attempt to find what I was looking for. This question isn't really something I could've made less broad. I agree that it's a bit short, but I honestly don't know what else to add (suggestions welcome). Also, there are plenty of other missile-related questions on here if you search around, so I don't think it's exactly off topic by that measure.

Unfortunately, missile related questions are often downvoted without providing a reason. However I would like to point out that not only are missiles accepted to be aircraft (per this question answer) but theses types of questions are also voted to be on topic, per this meta question

I am a bit uncertain what exactly you are searching for, however you can find  plenty of videos on the internet which show missiles hitting their target.

The AIM-9X Sidewinder development test video show the intercept of a F4 Phantom II by a Sidewinder AIM 9X infrared missile. Additionally, the infrared image of the missile is shown, which was telemetered down as part of the test suite, which is very interesting to see as it simultaneously gives the perspective of the missile. In my opinion, this is the best unclassified video showing an air-to-air intercept available.
The Russo-Ukrainian war is probably the most documented war ever. This also includes missile intercepts such as this video depicting the downing of a Mil MI-24 Helicopter
And of course a lot of videos exist of the Iron Dome system, which produces a big firework when intercepting incoming projectiles.


This is exactly what I was looking for. The question might’ve seemed broad, but this is what I was looking for. Thanks

One place you can find a lot of classic air combat footage is in the old Discovery Channel (back when it was good) documentary show Wings. Pick an episode about a missile-armed aircraft and enjoy an hour of aircraft and combat footage, plus 80s TV commercials! I picked the famously missile-only F-4 Phantom II and a quick skim caught footage of multiple air-to-air kills at 22:10. Unfortunately, most of the footage is unattributed so you rarely know what you're actually looking at.
Wings Playlist on YouTube.

Interesting footage. I honestly was trying to compare the ‘shoot down’ physics of games like DCS to the real world, and it seems fairly accurate!
